# EF6 Obtain complete description of a relationship

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm almost done with technical code that aims at partially synchronizing databases using EF6. But I'm still not comfortable with some scenarios.

All my pain comes to the fact that I need to establish first a good description of the `DBContext` including relationships. And I face difficulties to obtain (what I call) a complete description of a relationship between entities.

By complete description, I mean :

- Types from both ends
- Navigation Property (if exist) from both ends
- Relationship Multiplicity from both ends

To do this, I use MetadataWorkspace. In case of One-to-Many relationship, for example, I'm able to get this description if I obtain the NavigationProperty from EntityType that describe "Many" entity table. But, from EntityType that describe "One" entity table,I'm not able to find Inverse Navigation Property for example. Another issue comes when Navigation Property is not defined in both Entities : my code returns the property name twice.

To be more clear, here is a piece of code. I iterate on every DBset described in my context then on every Navigation property found in EntityType that describe the table (finally I manipulate TestResult List to create useful dictionaries `<Type, TableRelationshipDescription>`).

```
ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;

var dbSetList = typeof(SandBoxDbContext).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.Contains("DbSet")).ToList();

foreach (PropertyInfo p in dbSetList)
{
    Type sourceTableType = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
    EntityType table = GetTableEntityType(sourceTableType, workspace);
    typesVSOneRelationshipNavPropertyDict.Add(key: sourceTableType, value: new List<TableRelationshipDescription>());

    foreach (NavigationProperty np in table.NavigationProperties)
    {
        string sourceNavPropName = np.Name;
        var endMemberEntityType = np.ToEndMember.GetEntityType();
        var typeString = sourceTableType.Namespace + "." + endMemberEntityType.Name + "," + endMemberEntityType.NamespaceName;
        Type targetTableType = Type.GetType(typeString);
        string targetNavPropName = GetPropertyNameForNavigationProperty(np);

        if (np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity != RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
        {
            var tableRelationshipDescription = new TableRelationshipDescription()
                       {
                            FromTableType = sourceTableType,
                            FromNavigationProperty = sourceNavPropName,
                            FromMultiplicity = np.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity,
                            ToTableType = targetTableType,
                            ToNavigationProperty = targetNavPropName,
                            ToMultiplicity = np.FromEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity
                       };
            TestResult.Add(tableRelationshipDescription);
            // Trick to have a proper desc of the relationship from "one" side
            if (tableRelationshipDescription.ToMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
            {
                TestResult.Add(tableRelationshipDescription.GetReverseDescription());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and :

```
    private string GetPropertyNameForNavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navigationProperty)
    {
        var ForeignKeyName = navigationProperty.RelationshipType.Name.Split('_');
        var propertyName = ForeignKeyName[ForeignKeyName.Length - 1];
        return propertyName;
    }
```

In short... I need help

**EDIT :**
I don't need it anymore since I found the way to keep my entities attached during synchronization :-).

The reason why complete description was required is because I have to disconnect (nullable) relationships when an entity whose ID is used as foreign key in other tables is deleted. Keeping entities attached gives the opportunity to EF6 to manage this scenario from itself.

Ultimately I only need partial description of relationships (from table where foreign key is defined only) to add, update or disconnect related entities during the synchronization.

Should I leave this topic open in case its answer is of interest to other programmers ?

Alex